# Error downloading file with Internet Explorer using HTTPS

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, https

We recently have a problem with Internet Explorer when downloading files over HTTPS from one application. Suddenly it started to show this error

> Internet Explorer no puede descargar ${page} de ${domain}
>
> Internet Explorer no puede abrir este sitio Internet. El sitio solicitado no está disponible o no se encuentra. Intente de nuevo más tarde.

Translated to English

> Unable to download ${page} from ${domain}
>
> Internet Explorer was unable to open this site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later.

After searching for a while I discover a solution from microsoft (https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/kb/323308/en) which worked pretty fine, and user support team was able to rollout this to a very small set of users. Pretty fine.

Just apply a registry setting like this:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"BypassSSLNoCacheCheck"=dword:00000001
"BypassHTTPNoCacheCheck"=dword:00000001
```

Ok, perhaps it will be better to use `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` instead of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

Today I receive a call from another department on an application potentially affecting each employee of the company, like a bit of `<panic mode on />`. So I started to check with person developing this application and found one page where downloads were working and other were wasn't. Great, this gave us some room to play with Google Chrome Dev Tools to compare the one working with the one failing.

Basically on the failing one there was a Expire header like

```
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

Once the code was modified to remove this header it worked again with *unpatched* IE.

As far as it was working and suddenly started generating incidences we are worried what changed from one day to other so many users started suffering this errors. From my point of view 2 options are the more feasible:

1. Changes on the AD Group Policy. But no idea exactly which setting in policy.
2. Some patch installed on the users computers (this is regularly performed). But again no idea about which patch can cause this issue.

Anyone can point some other options?

Comment: Make sure your computers' time settings are correct. The computer which generated this header "Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" may have wrong time settings (probably BIOS battery is old).

Comment: @Jet That was not a bad time sync issue as far as in the code there was a instruction setting header to 0, which on computers time that's 01 Jan 1970 ...

Comment: You should mention the Internet Explorer versions involved, and whether it is likely that some machines have received IE patches or updates (you seem to indicate this might happen).  You might be able to query update history on machines effected/not to see if there is a specific patch issue.